# Laravel 5 public folder asset management

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a file stored in `public/files/sample.pdf`. When I want to download the file using `<a href="/public/files/sample.pdf">Download</a>`. It says not found. What will be the correct path. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/files/sample.pdf
```

You can always use

```
href="{{asset('files/sample.pdf')}}"
```

It will be easier

Answer (score 2):

You should apply url function instead of paste the directory directly.

```
<a href="{{url('/files/sample.pdf'}}">Download</a>
```

Comment: You gotta use curly braces

Comment: Thank you :P, that was a noobie mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking for a download response when clicking the link, you should have the URL link to a controller method.

```
<a href="{{ url('route/to/method') }}">
```

Now in the controller method

```
return response()->download(public_path('files/sample.pdf'));
```

[Laravel responses](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses)

Comment: This would be the right way when you want to hide files' actual path, otherwise a proper configurated server will send download headers automatically. So I don't think your method is a *should*.